# How to deal with Mary Sue NPCs

Tags: problem-gm, spotlight

This question is a bit different than the one [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74283/my-gm-has-created-a-mary-sue-npc-what-can-i-do-to-persuade-the-gm-to-make-her-l), because the NPC is not a jerk. In fact, they're actually quite nice. However, this is not the first time the GM has done this.

In our game, we have a legendary NPC on our side who just gets more and more likable and perfect the more we play. The NPC, who was a surprise addition, is legendary, ancient, immortal, and a messenger of the gods who is the most likable, friendly, charming, powerful, and humble NPC to ever NPC. The GM constantly emphasizes how great this NPC is, how much they love them, and how much everyone loves them, especially how powerful they are.

The GM has done this sort of thing before, with another NPC who was basically the same thing, except less charming and more brutal. But again, the legendary, unstoppable, utterly broken NPC who was the most powerful NPC to ever be powerful and had to have the final killshot of the game, and made the whole game about them and their destiny.

I don't want to just be a cheerleader to these people, but they're obviously self-inserts, so I don't want to offend. What do I do?

Comment: Is the game fun?

Comment: The game is fun when it's focused on the party! The GM is a good GM, and the story is great. However, every single time the Sue NPC is brought in, it grinds to a halt so that the NPC can take charge.

Comment: Consider adding that to the question. First, though, a few more questions: What percentage of a typical session focuses on the GM's super NPC? Do you know if the other players feel the same way? Is the plot on rails or does the GM appreciate and adapt to the unexpected? Has anyone talked to the GM about what seems to be this GM's preferred style of play (PCs forced to the background by NPCs)? (Also, it's easier to talk about an RPG when the system is known; then users familiar with that system can better understand the depth and breadth of the issue—consider adding a system tag.)

Comment: The percentage is usually at least twenty minutes of the NPCs talking to each other or the NPC having major discoveries or moments, out of a three hour session. I have talked to other players, and they agree when asked about it, but haven't privately raised any concerns. The system is 5e. The NPC also has private one-on-ones with other players, and side quests to take care of in text sessions. The most egregious example is a thirty minute joking session between two NPCs after I tried to start a serious conversation with another player right at the start.

Comment: Is this the same game/GM as [your other question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168565/how-to-deal-with-a-gm-who-favors-other-players)?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## Communicate your needs without judgement of the DM's decisions

It is good for a player to respectfully communicate issues they are having with the game because it makes it easier for the DM to know what the players are enjoying. The game doesn't just need to be fun for the players, however, it also needs to be fun for the GM. If that requires a Godlike DMPC that is their purview because otherwise there wouldn't be a game. If what your DM needs to enjoy the game and what you need directly conflict then you should leave the game.

When dealing with this issue, short of leaving the game, the best thing to do is frame your concerns in terms of how the game is meeting your needs and how it could be more enjoyable. Instead of approaching this as a problem of "The DM has a Mary Sue DMPC" you can approach it as "I would enjoy playing more if the PCs had a greater part in addressing the challenges. Could you have 'NPC' take a less active role so we can have more of a try?". By framing it in terms of your preferences and desires you can help the DM feel safe and respected and give them an opportunity to help you and the other players have a better experience.

Comment: Also: the correct terminology here (aka. the words that will yield more google results) is a DMPC (DM Player Charakter), and there is a reason that is an often mocked and/or hated trope.

Answer (score 4):

Try to work with it. Being a party of henchmen can be fun, as long as it's not for too long.

In a Pendragon campaign we'd occasionally meet Lancelot or Gawian. If we were traveling the same way, we could step back and let them handle the encounters. Travel was dangerous. It was nice being able to travel all the way to the Wall in 10 game minutes with full hit points. In fact, it was a little fun "tricking" our NPC heavy hitter into fighting black knights for us.

For important encounters, stud-boy rarely needs help. But he can't be everywhere. The players can be off rescuing people from the stables while the GM's alter-ego storms the castle. It's a nice change-up from "it's up to us to save the town". Just ask the NPC "so, what do you want us to do"?

In a less scrupulous campaign, the players get to clean up all of the gold Mr. Goody Two-shoes leaves on the corpses he creates. And it's somewhat fun to tell the local police "sure, we'll come with you, just be sure to let that 10 foot tall woman with glowing eyes -- you know, the one we came through the gates with -- know where we are".

If the GM is dead-set on having you watch their NPC be super-wonderful, none of that will work. But they might take the hint.

As far as NPC's talking to other NPC's, we used to have a contest -- try to get the GM to talk to themself, and for as long as possible (but our record was about 30 seconds -- the GM would catch on since we were all giggling as they switched between voices and say "well, eventually they work it out").